# Adding a decimal place if none exists

Tags: jquery, rounding

I have a list of dimensions the user enters, for the final output all items must have a decimal place - even if that value is .0

I've found lots of advice and responses on rounding a number to two decimal places, but nothing on adding if none exists.

Typically I'd sort this out afterwards with a bit of PHP but thought I'd see if it possible to do it live in browser with a bit of jquery magic.

I thought something along the lines of this would work but no

```
  $(".dimensions").keyup(function(){
    var value = $(this).val();
    var valueB = value.toFixed(1); 
    $(this).val(valueB);
}); 

$(".continuebutton").click(function( ){ 
    $(".dimensions").each(function() {
        var value = $(this).val();
        var valueB = value.toFixed(1); 
        $(this).val(valueB);
    });
});
```

basic setup: http://jsfiddle.net/shj1gp4g/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/a69j2jw4/

With `isNaN` check: http://jsfiddle.net/f2yjohpo/

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN
- `parseFloat` - to further get your head around check this: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1013-javascript-number-tofixed-method.htm

ho[pe it helps `:)`

Try this:

```
$(".continuebutton").click(function( ){ 
    $(".dimensions").each(function() {
        var value = $(this).val();  
        alert("WORKING! "+ parseFloat(value).toFixed(1) )
        var valueB = parseFloat(value).toFixed(1); 
        $(this).val(valueB);
    });
});
```

Comment: Works perfectly thanks, trimmed to down a bit and added values / compulsory numbers to the form to kick the NaN issue

Comment: @Tomate Saweet! glad it helped `:)`